# How to add curved tab when using TabRow and Tab with Compose and Material 3?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am trying to add the TabRow and Tab from Material 3 library on an Android Jetpack Compose application. The tab indicators are always in plain stroke and doesn't reflect the actual curved indicator as shown in the M3 website.

| From M3 Compose Code | From [M3 Website](https://m3.material.io/components/tabs/overview) |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 2 Tabs inside a TabRow] | [image: Note the primary example] |

```
TabRow(
    selectedTabIndex = periodIndex,
) {
    periodLabels.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
        Tab(
            selected = periodIndex == index,
            onClick = { periodIndex = index },
            text = { Text(
                text = title,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface
            ) }
        )
    }
}
```

How to get the version of Tab that resembles in the official design of M3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom indicator for the active indicator.

[image]

**Code**

```
@Composable
fun TabRowDemo() {
    var periodIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val periodLabels = listOf(
        "Upcoming",
        "Past",
    )

    BoxWithConstraints {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = periodIndex,
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                if (periodIndex < tabPositions.size) {
                    TabRowDefaults.PrimaryIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[periodIndex]),
                        width = maxWidth / periodLabels.size,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 3.dp,
                            topEnd = 3.dp,
                            bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                            bottomStart = 0.dp,
                        ),
                    )
                }
            },
        ) {
            periodLabels.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    selected = periodIndex == index,
                    onClick = {
                        periodIndex = index
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(
                            text = title,
                            maxLines = 1,
                            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the way to go, still need to calculate the width based on the text length which I can give a shot. But why is this not applied by default by the Compose Library team themselves as part of M3 guidelines is my question.

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan They have primary and secondary indicators. The default one is secondary. The primary is what you are looking for, but it requires the width to be provided or it takes a default fixed width. And also, there is a bug I see in the library, the primary shape is defined as all corners with `3.dp` which is not aligned with the M3 specs.